# Magento layered navigation not working with solr

Tags: magento, solr, search-engine, ca

The issue is when i enabled solr (i successfully configured solr and tested successfully) in magento enterprise,the layered navigation filter is not working properly.

i.e displaying all category products not filter with attributes value.

If i set "No" in Enable Solr Engine for Catalog Navigation in admin panel it's working fine.

Path : System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search -> Enable Solr Engine for Catalog Navigation -> set to "No"

I analysed magento enterprise search module,but they not adding custom attributes into solr params.like attr_nav_select_"custom_attribute"

```
ex : http://localhost.com:8080/solr/test/select/?q=wine%0D%0A&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=onq=test&qt=magento_en&fq=
%28visibility:3+OR+visibility:4%29+AND+store_id:13+AND+in_stock:true
```

Any one tell me is this magento issue or i need to configure any other matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please check the attributes are searchable or not, from admin manage attribute section.

Comment: hi i enabled all options for this attributes.

Comment: than please check is it creating the doc, with that attributes or not. pls update me, i will give you the file names also

Comment: Hi Dasarathi,thanks for your reply.its not creating with attributes.it's creating with default attributes only like store_id,category_ids,etc.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution.i update in catalog.xml under `<catalog_category_layered>`

```
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

changed to

```
    <reference name="left">
<block type="enterprise_search/catalog_layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

now i am getting attribute values in solr params like "attr_nav_select_brand:13"

```
http://localhost.com:8080/solr/test/select/?q=test&qt=magento_en&fq=(visibility:3+OR+visibility:4)+AND+(attr_nav_select_brand:13)+AND+store_id:3+AND+in_stock:true
```

but i don't know how to pass multiple values for specific attribute.any one guide me or suggest me how to make URL for multiple values for attribute.in default magento working with single value for attribute.

the category url like

```
http://localhost.com/whiskies.html?brand=Dreamer&mode=list&pack_size_in_litres=2+litres
```